# Edit automatically WHERE condition on query MySQL each three month

Tags: mysql, sql

I need edit automatically my **WHERE** condition on below query **SQL** each three month, executed on **MySQL database**:

```
SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE QS = 'variable';
```

From 01 january to 30 april the SQL query it must be :

```
SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE QS = 1;
```

From 01 may to 31 august the SQL query it must be :

```
SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE QS = 2;
```

From 01 september to 31 december the SQL query it must be :

```
SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE QS = 3;
```

Do anyone have an idea how to do ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT #1**

```
mysql> SELECT
    QUARTER ('2019-01-01') AS `1th q`,
    QUARTER ('2019-04-30') AS `1th q`,
    QUARTER ('2019-05-01') AS `2th q`,
    QUARTER ('2019-08-31') AS `2th q`,
    QUARTER ('2019-09-01') AS `3th q`,
    QUARTER ('2019-12-31') AS `3th q`;
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1th q | 1th q | 2th q | 2th q | 3th q | 3th q |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |     2 |     3 |     3 |     4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
1 row in set

mysql>
```

**Correct output :**

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1th q | 1th q | 2th q | 2th q | 3th q | 3th q |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |     2 |     2 |     3 |     3 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Those are four month periods...? Should they be?

Comment: Is `QS` a number or string?  It doesn't make sense to compare it to both types of values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff QS is a number

Comment: @APC Yes, QS is a column on my table, INT 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use quarter()  and curdate()

```
SELECT * 
FROM doTable 
WHERE QS = quarter(curdate());
```

Could be you are looking for 4 month period

```
select case when  month(curdate()) between 1 and 4  then 1
            when month(curdate()) between 5 and 8  then 2
            when   month(curdate()) between 9 and 12  then 3 end  as  four_month
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/99958

Comment: Thank you, did I get it right ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/99956/0

Comment: seems right  to me  ..  if you use curdate()   you can automatically  select the rows with matching ..  RS  ..

Comment: please see my **EDIT 1** in my first question, the output is wrong

Comment: in mysql  quaorter  are ... month 1-3   Q1  .. month 4-6 Q2  ...month 7-9 Q3 ...month 10-12 Q4 ..   ...'2019-04-30')  Q2   ..2019-05-01 Q2 ... Quarter  is the 12/3  4 quorter  ..  not 4 months ..

Comment: anyway answer  updated .. with a suggestion  of 4month